# Updating UIButton border color will delay?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We are using some bluetooth communication that send notification when connected to the main view controller, we get it by notification with :

```
- (void) receiveBLENotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"bluetooth"])
    {
      //here we log the title right on time but the next will happen only after a while
      NSLog(@"!!!!!!!");
     l1.layer.borderColor=[Globals sharedGlobals].mainColor.CGColor;
     l2.layer.borderColor=[Globals sharedGlobals].mainColor.CGColor;
```

So for some reason the color is changed but 6 seconds after we get the log.

Is there a way to force it to change ?

Comment: Is the whole UI frozen during those 6 seconds ?

Comment: I cant update any UI element in this time.

Comment: It means that the main thread is busy, and it updates the UI only when it's done. Do you perform any heavy operation when you receive your notification ?

Comment: yes, as i wrote, i am sending and receiving data over bluetooth from the iPhone...

Comment: Can you show that part of code ? You should consider using another thread.

Comment: thanks, well the code is big, i wonder which part of it. generally its another class that use CBCentral to connect to bluetooth, and it shows that all its activity are ended by that time.. strange.

Comment: you are not on the main thread - there are TONS of similar issues

Answer (score 0):

Solved that with this :

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //here you update all required ui
            });
```